# VB.NET SendGrid error "transportWeb" is not declared

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, sendgrid

SendGrid v6.3.4.0
VB 2017 Pro
on Windows 10 64b Pro

I want to add SendGrid email to my VB windows app.
I installed NuGet SendGrid to project (Add reference etc.) without problem.
But I get build error (see location in Sub send_by_SendGrid below): "transportWeb" is not declared.

This all works on my other computer.

```
Imports SendGrid
```

...

```
Sub send_by_SendGrid(ByVal Addr, ByVal Subject, ByVal Message, ByVal From_Address)

    ' Prevent email problem with Verizon:
    addr=replace(addr,"vzwpix","vtext",)

    if subject = "" then
        subject = " "
        'Message = ""   
    End If

    ' Create the email object first, then add the properties.
    Dim myMessage As SendGridMessage
    myMessage = New SendGridMessage()

    ' Add the message properties.
    myMessage.AddTo(Addr)
    myMessage.From = New MailAddress(From_Address)


    if Subject <> "" then
        myMessage.Subject = Subject
    end if

    ' Add plain text body only:
    myMessage.Text = Message

    Dim username As String
    Dim pswd As String
    username = "MYUSERNAME@azure.com"
    pswd = "MY_PW"



    Dim credentials As NetworkCredential  

    credentials = New NetworkCredential(username, pswd)
    ' // Create an Web transport for sending email.
    transportWeb = New Web(credentials) <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  'transportWeb' is not declared

    transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage)  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<   'transportWeb' is not declared
End Sub
```

Comment: looks like you need to declare transportWeb

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
transportWeb = New Web(credentials)
```

to

```
Dim transportWeb As New Web(credentials)
```